# A pickup for cymbals

Tags: detection, electromagnetic

I'm trying to find ideas how to capture just the sound of the cymbal(s) of a drum kit - while the entire kit is being played. As cymbals are made of bronze, they are not magnetic and that rules out normal electromagnetic pickups. Optical systems probably struggle with the fact that there is quite a lot of movement when a drummer strikes the cymbal hard:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpoanOlb3-w

I do have access to normal microphones, but I'm looking for a different approach. The sound of the pickup does not have to be "perfect" or very natural. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're looking for sound, a microphone is probably the thing to use.  If there are other constraints on you design that can tell us why you're looking for an alternate approach, please let us know what they are.

Comment: I'm looking for maximum isolation, but unusual (as long as it's somehow usable, not super duper lo-fi) sound is a plus. I already have tools to get just the drum sounds, without any cymbals. I just figured there might be some clever way of capturing the cymbals separately too as they are made of metal (using eddy currents etc.)

Answer (score 2):

One quite intuitive possibility is to put a piezo sensor where you can capture the vibration of the cymbal, that is in the junction with the stand.

Comment: Some of the cymbal energy is transferred to the stand, but probably not much. I have a few different condenser contact mikes I can try there; they usually sound better than piezo. Thanks!

Comment: @Jari indeed they probably sound better than piezo, but maybe you could give them a try if you're considering a "silent" version of the drum kit. Also, I proposed because you were looking for alternatives to mikes, and they probably isolate better the sound from the other pieces.

Answer (score 2):

I would not rule out magnetic pickups so quickly. Bronze is electrically conductive so you could consider a reluctance pickup (which would require a permanent magnet).

Such a pickup would have an output proportional to frequency, but if the cymbal has a response like this one:

[image: http://www.lutins.co.uk/resonances/sabi10inSplsh-1857hz-freqs.jpeg]

.. it may be possible to equalize it over a reasonable range.

Comment: Never heard of reluctance pickups before, I need to research them. Thanks for the tip!